# Running a video with QMediaPlayer : undefined symbol

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qmediaplayer, qtmultimedia

I’m trying to run a simple application that plays a video with Qt Multimedia, but I got the following error:

```
`(TestMultimedia:17734): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfcdec.so': /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfcdec.so: undefined symbol: __gst_debug_min`
```

It looks like I have a wrong version of libgstfcdec.so. Am i right and how to solve this issue?

Can any one help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get a version having that symbol or change the internals to use symbols from your version.

Comment: How to do it ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did you build it yourself, or it was installed from distribution package?

Comment: I didn't build anything. Just installed the gtsreamer plugins (ith yum) and run a simple test with QMediaPlayer.

Comment: Which Qt version exactly are you using?

Comment: I compiled the same code with Qt 5.2 and i got the same error. Any help please ?

Comment: The same error above : (TestMultimedia:11793): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfcdec.so': /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfcdec.so: undefined symbol: __gst_debug_min
Error: "Internal data stream error."